# hide profile title in Fieldset (legend)

Tags: developer

Is there a way to hide the profile title.  I have added a tracking profile which is being populated by values passed in the URL to the contribute page. The fields I have added are being hidden, so the title is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use CSS to have something like the following

```
.whatevercontext fieldset.crm-profile-id-13 legend {
  display: none
}
```

and then put that into your site's theme CSS file alongside other customizations you do for your site.  Alternatively, you could create a special CSS file and enter the URL in **Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs**.  Both methods avoid hacking CiviCRM's CSS code.

However, you should double-check the affected form(s) after each upgrade just to make sure the selector hasn't changed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I will make the changes to the site's theme CSS file.

Comment: Given I did not want to display any of the content associated with the class "crm-profile-id-13" I went with the selector "fieldset.crm-profile-id-13", so that I would not display the title or the line associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do something similar with jQuery and hide it via an extra.tpl file documented here:

https://civicrm.org/blogs/dave-greenberg/now-its-easier-add-custom-behaviors-templates

Answer (score 1):

Examined the source, determine the class value for the fieldset, and add an entry to the style sheet (civicrm.css).

fieldset.crm-profile-id-13 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

I do not like changing production files, so I will do some addition research to determine a better location for the change.  Is there a custom style sheet for profiles?

Comment: could you please post a separate new question about how to add custom css to CiviCRM? Things get messy when an answer also contains a question, and that one deserves to be on its own.